# Python v2.7.7 - Error 5 Access Denied but file copies anyway

Tags: python

```
>>> import shutil
>>> shutil.copy2('c:/trash/1.txt','r:/1.txt')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Python27\lib\shutil.py", line 131, in copy2
    copystat(src, dst)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\shutil.py", line 100, in copystat
    os.chmod(dst, mode)
WindowsError: [Error 5] Access is denied: 'r:/1.txt'
```

Was wondering if someone could shed some light on this. This is happening under elevated prompt via Windows. I've remounted the share, confirmed permissions, made sure UAC is off as well.

I'm trying to do a copy of the file to R: which is a network share (freenas). Have had no issue up until the last 2 days when this started happening. Now the strange thing is, even though it's coming up with an error, the file copies anyway.

Tested on multiple other PC's in the same network and only 1 other is having the same issue, but seemingly no source or idea how this problem came about. Thoughts?

Comment: I am not sure how much this comment may help you, but try change the '/' to '\\' and see if it helps.

Comment: Note that it is the chmod that fails, not the copy

Comment: yes its the problem with admin, try my solution - it will work. good luck

Comment: Ah correct, just shutil.copy does work but copy2 gives the above error...

Answer (score 0):

### Hackish Workaround

It's visible by looking in your trace's output, `shutil.copy2` fails changing the file's permissions right after it copied it to your network share.
This implies you have permissions misconfiguration in your linux network share server.

To workaround this, use this function instead

```
shutil.copyfile(r'c:\trash\1.txt',r'r:\1.txt')
```

---

Iv'e experienced the same issue while copying a file into a linux based network share from a windows machine

Answer (score -1):

Because you have to have the "system administrator privileges" to do this. So try run the script with system administrators privilege.

Run this in an administrator command prompt

To start a command prompt as an administrator

1. Click Start menu.
2. In Search bar, type cmd, and then press CTRL+SHIFT+ENTER.
3. Run the python script, it will run as admin.

Comment: Just attempted this, no go. Any other suggestions?

Thank you for taking the time btw, appreciate the assistance :)

Comment: can you try making sure you have read/write permissions on that file? running as admin should give that permission. Error 5 is a permission issue.